# Three JS Font not recognized

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to use TextGeometry to add text to my project

```
var shape = new THREE.TextGeometry( 'Hello, World!', {
      size: 60,
      height: 20,
      curveSegments: 3,
      font: 'helvetiker',
      weight: 'normal',
      bevelThickness: 3,
      bevelSize: 3,
      bevelEnabled: true
    });
    var wrapper = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
    var words = new THREE.Mesh(shape, wrapper);
    scene.add(words);
```

The error I get from the console is "The font Helvetiker with normal weight and normal style is missing."

I have included the font and typeface.js in the html and they have been loaded correctly

```
    <script src="http://typeface.neocracy.org/typeface-0.15.js"></script>
    <script src="http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.js"></script>
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be fantastic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vtLj5ntt/) shows a working example of your code.

```
var shape = new THREE.TextGeometry("Hello, World!", {
    size: 60,
    height: 20,
    curveSegments: 3,
    font: 'helvetiker',
    weight: 'normal',
    bevelThickness: 3,
    bevelSize: 3,
    bevelEnabled: true
});
```

The inclusion of the typeface library might be the problem

Answer (score 0):

I was adding the font file before the inclusion of three js. Adding this after three js fixed the issue